# Clearing badge number Appcelerator studio, arrowdb and iOS?

Tags: titanium, push, appcelerator, arrowdb

So i send push notifications using the arrowdb and cloud service with Appcelerator. This seems to work well and the iphone gets the notification. What i wonder is if there is some easy way to clear the badge numer to 0? It needs to be reset at the arrowdb server as well (or apple) i guess.

I want the badge to be reset every time the app is opened.

What i did was adding a resume listener in alloy.js

```
Ti.App.addEventListener("resumed", function(e){
```

In the event listener i first do (to reset the badge locally):

```
Cloud.PushNotifications.resetBadge({
        device_token: device_token
    }, function (e) {
        if (e.success) {
            Ti.API.info('Badge Reset!');
        }
        else {
            Ti.API.error(e);
        }
    });
```

Then i also send a push to clear the badge on the server like this by sending a push to ourself:

```
var push_payload = {
        badge:0,
        sound:"",
        alert:"",
        title:"",
        message_text:"",
        push_type:"clear",
        from_user:Alloy.Globals.currentUser.id,
        vibrate:false
    };

    Cloud.PushNotifications.notify({
        channel: 'private_message',
        payload: push_payload,
        to_ids: Alloy.Globals.currentUser.id
    }, function (e) {
        if (e.success) {
            Ti.API.info('Success sending push notification');
        } else {
            Ti.API.info('Error sending push: '+((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
        }
    });
```

The event listener seems to be called, and the push is sent. But somehow the badge still remains on the iphone device... Should I do this differently?

Answer (score 4):

Did you try this ?

```
Titanium.UI.iOS.appBadge = 0
```

Comment: It seems we've been answering almost at same time, sorry Juan, I didn't mean to give just another slightly different solution! :)

Comment: jajaja, looks like but there are no problem..as long as the answer can help @Emil

Comment: Actually your is correct!  As in the latest docs, setAppBadge is in Titanium.UI.iOS, no more in Titanium.UI.iPhone (I checked now and I've been using it in a quite old project on 3.5.2 SDK)

Comment: But this just sets it locally? The badge number will remain on servers? Also need the same for Android eventually I guess, anyone have a solution for that too?

Comment: `Titanium.UI.iOS.setAppBadge()` sets the badge value locally; if the argument is 0 the badge will disappear from your app icon. When the app will receive a new notification along with a new badge value, this value will be set as the new badge number. 
Instead Android does not natively use similar badge numbers on the app icon.

Comment: I tried this now too. The badge keeps being "1" for the app icon. Seems it does not reset for some reason...

Comment: I see, I remember being somehow confused too while attempting to clean the app badge locally. While I'm aware of what the documentation for Cloud.PushNotifications.resetBadge states, I couldn't have it working that way. In my app I had a section where users get custom made notification messages (i.e. about being followed, or some of their content liked by other users), so I went to clean app badge when that particular view got focus, in the callback of a "focus" eventListener I added to the view's controller. It sounds tricky, and it actually is, but I got to clean the badge in this way. Hth.

Answer (score 0):

to clean the badge number, in a project I did some times ago, I successfully used

```
Ti.UI.iPhone.setAppBadge(0);
```

Hope it will work for you too.

Comment: ok, that was 3.5.2 SDK, shame on me (not to check the doc before posting)  :D

Comment: my bad, that `Ti.UI.iPhone.setAppBadge` existed in the old SDK I was using at that time, not anymore in the latest one.

Answer (score 0):

For Android use: `Ti.Android.NotificationManager.cancelAll()`

This command clears the notification and badge

Comment: Do you know by any chance how to read the current badge number before 'cancelAll' it ?